# hadoop can't start ./sbin/start-dfs.sh

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I had started shall( ./sbin/start-dfs.sh )

1. jps

   ```
    3098 Jps<br>
    2492 NameNode<br>
    2700 SecondaryNameNode
   ```
2. hadoop-datanode-log

   ```
    2017-02-15 15:55:12,787 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Failed to add storage directory [DISK]file:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/%3E/data/hadoop/hdfs/datanode/
   java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/>/data/hadoop/hdfs/datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-4c9d5df1-10c6-45cb-9fe0-e1631e4d13e2; datanode clusterID = CID-6dc3d755-f713-4bec-a62a-c47e96dcbc0d
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:775)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadStorageDirectory(DataStorage.java:300)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadDataStorage(DataStorage.java:416)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.addStorageLocations(DataStorage.java:395)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:573)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1362)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1327)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:317)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:223)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:802)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   2017-02-15 15:55:12,792 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting.
   java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:574)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1362)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1327)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:317)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:223)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:802)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   2017-02-15 15:55:12,793 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
   2017-02-15 15:55:12,799 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned)
   2017-02-15 15:55:14,800 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
   2017-02-15 15:55:14,802 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
   2017-02-15 15:55:14,803 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have formatted the namenode on a working cluster,

Delete the data directories and start the datanode process again in all nodes.

```
rm -rf <dfs.datanode.data.dir>

./sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```